# StartsWith Function Python

Tags: python, startswith

Anyone know what code I could use instead of the below? Could I use "startswith" instead of individual where clauses? How do I do this?

```
ds_4['New_Domain'] = np.where(ds_4['Domain'] == 'Alcohol,animals,children,crime', 'Alcohol', ds_4.Domain)
ds_4['New_Domain'] = np.where(ds_4['Domain'] == 'Alcohol,campaign-finance,ethics,public-service', 'Alcohol', ds_4.New_Domain)
ds_4['New_Domain'] = np.where(ds_4['Domain'] == 'Alcohol,candidates-biography', 'Alcohol', ds_4.New_Domain)
ds_4['New_Domain'] = np.where(ds_4['Domain'] == 'Alcohol,candidates-biography,crime', 'Alcohol', ds_4.New_Domain)
ds_4['New_Domain'] = np.where(ds_4['Domain'] == 'Alcohol,children', 'Alcohol', ds_4.New_Domain)
ds_4['New_Domain'] = np.where(ds_4['Domain'] == 'Alcohol,children,crime,public-health,public-safety', 'Alcohol', ds_4.New_Domain)
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a try with `startswith` like below because,`startswith` allows a **string** or **tuple** as its first argument.

```
ds_4.loc[ds_4['Domain'].str.startswith(('Alcohol,animals,children,crime','Alcohol,campaign-finance,ethics,public-service','Alcohol,candidates-biography','Alcohol,candidates-biography,crime','Alcohol,children','Alcohol,children,crime,public-health,public-safety'), na=False), 'New_Domain'] = "Alcohol"
```

Comment: this should be faster than `apply`, but i'm pretty sure you need to add `loc` since you're also indexing a column: `ds_4.loc[ds_4['Domain'].str.startswith(......), 'New_Domain'] = 'Alcohol'`

Comment: @tdy Thanks for pointing out, I did that mistake while writing. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly what you are trying to achieve, you could use `apply`:

```py
ds_4['New_Domain'] = ds_4['Domain'].apply(lambda val: 'Alcohol' if str(val).startswith('Alcohol') else val)
```

This will get you a new column `New_Domain` whose value, for each row, will be 'Alcohol' if the corresponding value in `Domain` starts with 'Alcohol'; otherwise, it will return the value of `Domain`.